# What are the latest textbooks (lernolibroj) for learning Esperanto?

Tags: learning

I don't mean reference-style books, as I'm aware of the formidable PMEG.

What I'm looking for are books that teach Esperanto in a method similar to that of a school book.

I know of two main ones - *Esperanto Learning and Using the International Language* and *Teach Yourself Esperanto* - but the latest publish dates on those that I can find are 2004 and 1992, respectively.

I enjoy learning from a textbook, so when I started learning Esperanto, I was disappointed by the lack of new, up-to-date, recent material, so I settled on the 2004 publication I mentioned above.  And I've been told it is on the verge of being out of date.

Is anyone aware of anything else?  I've heard rumors that the people at Teach Yourself could possibly be considering an update.  Can anyone validate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question depends somewhat on the language of instruction. The book ["Esperanto: Learning and Using the International Language"](http://esperanto-usa.org/retbutiko/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=140&products_id=5140) by David Richardson is still the most common one in use for teaching native English speakers, and it is published by Esperanto USA.  I do not believe there is a newer Esperanto textbook targeting beginning English speaking students that uses the standard "language class" method of teaching.

In addition to the book by Richardson and the "Teach Yourself" books, Esperanto USA publishes an older book called ["Step by Step in Esperanto"](http://esperanto-usa.org/retbutiko/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=140&products_id=15760).  They also list other books targeted to English speakers in their [bookstore](http://esperanto-usa.org/retbutiko/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=20_240_410).

Edukado, a site devoted to the teaching of Esperanto, maintains a [library catalog](http://edukado.net/biblioteko/libroj) of lernlibroj that is searchable by language, method of instruction, and other categories.

The [Internacia Ligo de Esperantistaj Instruistoj](http://www.ilei.info/index.php?lingvo=eo), an organization of Esperanto teachers, also publishes a magazine, [Internacia Pedagogia Revuo](http://www.ilei.info/revuoj/index.php?lingvo=eo), that discusses such things, although it is in Esperanto.